# How can i retrieve an array of geopoints that are saved in a firestore database to a latLng arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I stored a couple of geopoints in a geopoint array in firebase database

```
      CollectionReference propRef = db.collection("Prpoerty");
         propRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new     OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = document.getGeoPoint("vertex");
                    double lat = geoPoint.getLatitude();
                    double lng = geoPoint.getLongitude();
                    points.add (new LatLng(lat, lng));
                }
            } else {
                Log.w("foobar", "Error getting documents.",     task.getException());
            }
        }


    });
        System.out.println(points);
```

I expected something like a standard latlng arrayList.
But instead got

> Displays Error   java.lang.RuntimeException: Field 'vertex' is not a
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.castTypedValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@20.1.0:562)

[Screenshot of firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJEXj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All array type fields in Firestore will come back as List type objects.  You need to write your code to expect a `List<Object>`, then cast each item to `GeoPoint`.

Comment: I cast it with `for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        List<GeoPoint> geoPoint = (List<GeoPoint>) document.getGeoPoint("vertex");
                        System.out.println(geoPoint);
//                        points.add (new LatLng(geoPoint));
                    }` but still had the same error

Comment: and if i cast it to latlng i get  `GeoPoint { latitude=0.321732, longitude=32.621223 }, GeoPoint { latitude=0.32181, longitude=32.621215 }, GeoPoint { latitude=0.321828, longitude=32.621226 }...` which isnt what i want. Am looking to get something like this `GeoPoint {0.321732,32.621223 },{0.32181,32.621215 } ...`

Comment: Did you try casting to `List<Object>`, then each item individually, as I suggested?

Comment: oh yes I did.   And i got this `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference`

Comment: this is what i did  **List<Object> geoPoint = (List<Object>) document.get("vertex");
                        for (Object geoObject : geoPoint){
                            GeoPoint gp = (GeoPoint) geoPoint;
                            points.add(new LatLng(gp.getLatitude(),gp.getLongitude()));
                        }**

Comment: Looks like geoPoint or some gp was null in that case, which means there was no field called vertex.  I suggest you use a debugger to more closely examine the contents of the objects you're dealing with.

Comment: the Debugger shows that the document being referenced is Something different called Names. I cant figure out why

Comment: Thank you. Your Advice helped me out. Got it working as i wanted